# How to fix class function "prototype does not match" and "cadidate is" errors

Tags: c++, class

I'm desperately trying to finish this last assignment, and I'm at a complete loss for what these errors are trying to tell me to do. The errors are as such:

"prototype for 'double Rectangle::calculateArea()' does not match any in class 'Rectangle'" (line 40)

"candidate is: int Rectangle::calculateArea()" (line 11)

"prototype for 'double Rectangle::calculatePerimeter()' does not match any in class 'Rectangle'" (line 45)

"candidate is: int Rectangle::calculatePerimeter()" (line 12)

This is my first post on this forum, so I apologize in advance for it being ill-formatted

I haven't tried anything because none of the solutions I've found on forums relate directly to my problem (or so I think).

Thank you

```
// Rectangle.cpp
using namespace std;
class Rectangle
{
public: 
  void setLength(double length);
  void setWidth(double width);
  double getLength();
  double getWidth();

  int calculateArea() {return width*length;}
  int calculatePerimeter() {return (width*2) + (length*2);}


private:    
  double length;
  double width;
}; 

void Rectangle::setLength(double len)
{
  len = length;
}

void Rectangle::setWidth(double wid)
{
  wid = width;
}

double Rectangle::getLength()
{
  return length;
}

double Rectangle::getWidth()
{
  return width;
}

double Rectangle::calculateArea()
{
  return (width*length)
}

double Rectangle::calculatePerimeter()
{
  return ((width*2) + (length*2))
}
```

Comment: The functions have different return types in the declarations (inside the class definition) and in the definitions. And they have two definitions one in the class definition and other outside the class definition

Comment: You haven't explained what that code is supposed to do.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes. Why?

Comment: @melpomene For me it looks strange. There is a class definition and nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

You already defined the functions in the class definition with a wrong return type (int instead of double)

```
class Rectangle
{
  //...
  int calculateArea() {return width*length;}
  int calculatePerimeter() {return (width*2) + (length*2);}
  //..
};
```

And then you redefined them outside the class

```
double Rectangle::calculateArea()
{
  return (width*length)
}

double Rectangle::calculatePerimeter()
{
  return ((width*2) + (length*2))
}
```

Also these functions are defined incorrectly

```
void Rectangle::setLength(double len)
{
  len = length;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

void Rectangle::setWidth(double wid)
{
  wid = width;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

They must be defined like

```
void Rectangle::setLength(double len)
{
  length = len;
}

void Rectangle::setWidth(double wid)
{
  width = wid;
}
```

And all these functions

```
  double getLength();
  double getWidth();

  int calculateArea() {return width*length;}
  int calculatePerimeter() {return (width*2) + (length*2);}
```

should be declared with the qualifier const

```
  double getLength() const;
  double getWidth() const;

  double calculateArea() const {return width*length;}
  ^^^^^^
  double calculatePerimeter() const {return (width*2) + (length*2);}
  ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler literally tells you!

It says that these two things don't match:

```
 int Rectangle::calculateArea()
 double Rectangle::calculateArea()
```

And, well, that's true. Your return types differ.

Pick one and use it consistently.